# Replacing a subset of table values with a list of vectors

Tags: r, list, vector

I have a table as follows:

```
tableA <- structure(c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), dim = c(3L, 
                                                                   5L), dimnames = structure(list(c("X", "Y", 
                                                                                                    "Z"), c("A", "B", "C","D", "E")), names = c("", "")), class = "table")

    A B C D E
  X 1 0 0 3 0
  Y 0 0 6 0 0
  Z 0 6 0 0 1
```

And a list of vectors as follows:

```
    listB <- list(
        "X" = c(0, 0, 0, 4, 0),
        "Y" = c(0, 0, 5, 0, 0),
        "Z" = c(0, 7, 0, 0, 0))
```

I would like to replace all values in table A, of columns `B,C, and D`, that are bigger than zero, with the corresponding values of list B.

Desired output:

```
    A B C D E
  X 1 0 0 4 0
  Y 0 0 5 0 0
  Z 0 7 0 0 1
```

Is there any way to copy these values in such manner?

Comment: @sindri_baldur Apologies. I fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* do the following

```
cols2replace  = match(c('B', 'C', 'D'), colnames(tableA))
cells2replace = tableA[, cols2replace] > 0
    
tableB = matrix(unlist(listB), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
tableA[, cols2replace][cells2replace] = tableB[, cols2replace][cells2replace]

> tableA
   
    A B C D E
  X 1 0 0 4 0
  Y 0 0 5 0 0
  Z 0 7 0 0 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I posted a related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72907265/replacing-positive-table-values-with-positive-values-from-a-list-of-uneven-vecto

Answer (score 3):

As @Chris rightly pointed out the prior logic on the matrix.data.frame() couldn't use the column index vector, adjusted below:

Base R solution:

```
dfA <- as.data.frame.matrix(tableA)

ir <- data.frame(
  Map(function(x, y){ifelse(x > 0, y, x)},
      dfA,
      setNames(
        data.frame(t(as.data.frame(listB))),
        names(tableA)
      )
  ),
  row.names = row.names(tableA)
)

col_idx <- !grepl(paste0(c('^B$', '^C$', '^D$'), collapse = "|"), colnames(ir))

ir[,col_idx] <- dfA[,col_idx]
```

Comment: Ah yes, those pesky `A` & `E`.

Comment: @Chris couldn't agree more.

Comment: @Chris did this persist?

Comment: @Chris i truly hope so haha (yes)

Comment: @Chris no i cleaned my environment and it doesnt work

Comment: you are correct thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @Chris reverted back to previous solution for the most part.

Comment: Okay, now for the unwashed, explain, for future readers, the very nice `!grepl(` and it's impact on the otherwise expanded `ir`, from which we will all learn, and I will also delete this...

Comment: @Chris `grepl()` in  conjunction with the `^` and `$` prefix and suffix respectively, and the `paste0(, collapse = "|")` concatenates the vector into a regex string looking for columns named B...D respectively (the caret `^` and `$` mean start and end of the string-so the pattern looks for `B` and nothing else `C` and nothing else `D` and nothing else in the string) - with `grepl()` returning a logical vector denoting whether or not those column names were found in the `ir` data.frame's column names. This is then logically negated so we can find all other columns that don't match.

Comment: @Chris hope that's informative.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72907265/replacing-positive-table-values-with-positive-values-from-a-list-of-uneven-vecto