# Replacing positive table values with positive values from a list of uneven vectors

Tags: r, list, vector

## Background

I recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899527/replacing-a-subset-of-table-values-with-a-list-of-vectors). I however made the example slightly too simple, so I am adding some complexity here, where the vector length is no longer equal to the table length.

## Problem

I have a table as follows:

```
tableA <- structure(c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 6L, 0L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), dim = c(3L, 
                                                                   5L), dimnames = structure(list(c("X", "Y", 
                                                                                                    "Z"), c("A", "B", "C","D", "E")), names = c("", "")), class = "table")

    A B C D E
  X 1 0 0 3 0 (two positive numbers)
  Y 0 4 6 0 0 (two positive numbers)
  Z 0 6 1 0 1 (three positive numbers)
```

And a list of vectors as follows:

```
    listB <- list(
        "X" = c(0, 4),
        "Y" = c(4, 5),
        "Z" = c(7, 1, 0))
```

The vectors are not equal, but the amount of numbers in the vectors equal the amount **positive** numbers in the table.

I would like to replace all values in `tableA`, of columns `B,C, and D`, that are bigger than zero, with the corresponding values of `listB`.

Desired output:

```
    A B C D E
  X 1 0 0 4 0
  Y 0 4 5 0 0
  Z 0 7 1 0 1
```

## Previous answer

The [original answer by sindri_baldur](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72899779/8071608) suggested the following:

```
cols2replace  = match(c('B', 'C', 'D'), colnames(tableA))
cells2replace = tableA[, cols2replace] > 0
    
tableB = matrix(unlist(listB), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
tableA[, cols2replace][cells2replace] = tableB[, cols2replace][cells2replace]
```

In my actual data however the vectors in the list of vectors are unequal. Therefore:

```
tableB = matrix(unlist(listB), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
```

Does not work.

## Suggestion

I am wondering if I cannot simply get all positive values from `tableA`, replace them with all positive values of of `listB` (so that values which are `0` in `listB` are not replaced) and then put them back in the table. I started as follows:

```
# Get all positive values from the table
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
out <- tableA %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -rn) %>% 
   filter(str_detect(value, '\\b0\\b', negate = TRUE)) %>% 
   group_by(rn) %>% 
   summarise(freq = list(value), .groups = 'drop')
```

But the code does not work on a table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume the amount of numbers in each vector in `listB` equals the amount of positive numbers in each row of `tableA`, you could solve it by

```r
tab <- t(tableA)
tab[tab > 0] <- unlist(listB)
tableA[, c('B', 'C', 'D')] <- t(tab)[, c('B', 'C', 'D')]
tableA

#    A B C D E
#  X 1 0 0 4 0
#  Y 0 4 5 0 0
#  Z 0 7 1 0 1
```

Comment: @Darren Tsai superb

Answer (score 0):

You could also solve your problem as follow:

```
x = unlist(listB)
tableA = t(tableA)
tableA[c("B", "C", "D"), ][which(tableA[c("B", "C", "D"), ]>0)] = x[x>0]
tableA = t(tableA)

  A B C D E
X 1 0 0 4 0
Y 0 4 5 0 0
Z 0 7 1 0 1
```